# How to prevent getting character(0) when web scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping different names of weed variants from a data set and keep getting `character(0)`. I am using the SelectorGadget tool to wrangle the names of the variants. All names are included, no `NA`s.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
weed_data<-read_html("https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/corykjar/leafly-cannabis-strains-dataset?resource=download")
strain_name<-weed_data%>%
html_nodes(".hdFafr div:nth-child(2)")%>%
html_text()
strain_name
```

Comment: Why don't you download the `strains_cleaned.csv` from your shown url and import it using `read.csv()` or `readr`s `read_csv()`?

Answer (score 2):

So as was suggested in the comments, creating an account and just downloading the dataset is probably the easiest, but if you want to scrape this, here's one way to do that.

It looks like the problem is that table content is delivered after a script runs, so the webpage `rvest` sees is different from the page that a user sees when they navigate to the page. One possible way to overcome this problem is to use `RSelenium` to automate the web browser to navigate to the page, wait for the script to deliver the table, then read the html and extract the node we want.

There's a further problem in that the table only loads as the user scrolls down, so I had to add a while loop to scroll until the bottom of the page is reached.

Here's an example:

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

# define target url
url <- "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/corykjar/leafly-cannabis-strains-dataset?resource=download"


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4550L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# open the remote driver-------------------------------------------------------
remDr$open()

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)

# pull the webpage html
# then read it
page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()



# figure out how many records there are: 

number_of_total_records <- page_html %>% 
                          html_nodes(".sc-cmwCue") %>% 
                          html_text() %>% 
                          as.numeric()


# Another problem is that the whole table doesn't load 
# all at once, it loads dynamically as the user scrolls
# down. So we're going to replicate that using a while
# loop

# define a variable for the number of records we've pulled
number_of_pulled_records <- 0


# now we execute the code inside the while loop
# until the number of pulled records is equal to the number
# of total records
while (number_of_pulled_records  < number_of_total_records) {
  
  
  # first we find the element that corresponds to the table
  webElem <- remDr$findElement("css selector", ".sc-cXzqcO")
  
  # then we tell RSelenium to scroll to the bottom of that element
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
  
  # unfortnately that only scrolls to the bottom of the 
  # current table and doesn't count the rows that just loaded
  # as the bottom of the table, so we have to keep scrolling
  # the while loop is how we decide when to stop scrolling
  
  # pull the new html
  page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html()
  

  # find the nodes we care about
  # the first node is the class for each row
  # then pull the child node corresponding to the second column or the strain name
  
  pulled_results <- page_html %>% 
    html_nodes("span.sc-cCYyox") %>% 
    html_nodes("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)") %>%
    html_text()
  
  
  
  # now we see how many results we pulled
  # if the number is equal to the total number
  # we stop pulling, otherwise the while loop keeps
  # scrolling down the page
  
  
  number_of_pulled_records <- length(pulled_results)
  
  
}
```

### results

```
> head(pulled_results, 30)
 [1] "Ice Cream Cake"       "Gelato"               "Blue Dream"           "Sour Diesel"          "Dosidos"             
 [6] "Apple Fritter"        "GSC"                  "Zkittlez"             "OG Kush"              "Mac 1"               
[11] "Biscotti"             "Purple Punch"         "White Widow"          "Jack Herer"           "Mimosa"              
[16] "Sherbert"             "Pineapple Express"    "Cereal Milk"          "GMO Cookies"          "Durban Poison"       
[21] "White Runtz"          "Peanut Butter Breath" "Kush Mints"           "Northern Lights"      "Green Crack"         
[26] "Gushers"              "MAC"                  "Slurricane"           "Sundae Driver"        "Pink Runtz"          


> tail(pulled_results, 30)
 [1] "Slice of Heaven"          "Brian Berry Citrus Blend" "Rigger Kush"              "White Empress"           
 [5] "Crosswalker"              "Golden Calyx"             "Altoyd"                   "White Master"            
 [9] "Ozma"                     "Short and Sweet"          "Sergerbloom Haze"         "Somaui"                  
[13] "Diabla"                   "Afghooey"                 "Medikit"                  "Sweet Nina"              
[17] "Beckwourth Bud"           "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"  
[21] "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"  
[25] "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"  
[29] "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"   "Crockett’s Sour Tangie"  


> length(pulled_results)
[1] 5120


> length(unique(pulled_results))
[1] 5106
```

It looks like the last result got repeated a few times, but that should be pretty easy to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle provides API to access datasets, though you do need to create an account to get your access token. `kaggle.json` with a token can then be downloaded from https://www.kaggle.com/me/account and accessing datasets might look something like this:

```r
library(httr2)
kaggle_token <- jsonlite::read_json("kaggle.json")
request("https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1") %>% 
  req_url_path_append("datasets/download/corykjar/leafly-cannabis-strains-dataset/strains_cleaned.csv") %>% 
  req_auth_basic(kaggle_token$username, kaggle_token$key) %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_string() %>% 
  readr::read_csv()

#> # A tibble: 5,120 × 10
#>     ...1 Name           Type  Alias Rating Num_Reviews `THC%` Other_Cannabinoids
#>    <dbl> <chr>          <chr> <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  <chr>             
#>  1     0 Ice Cream Cake Indi… <NA>     4.6        1039 THC 2… CBG 1%            
#>  2     1 Gelato         Hybr… aka …    4.6        2219 THC 1… CBD 0%            
#>  3     2 Blue Dream     Hybr… <NA>     4.3       14300 THC 1… CBD 0%            
#>  4     3 Sour Diesel    Sati… aka …    4.3        8264 THC 1… CBD 0%            
#>  5     4 Dosidos        Hybr… aka …    4.6        1073 THC 2… CBG 1%            
#>  6     5 Apple Fritter  Hybr… <NA>     4.5         346 THC 2… CBD 0%            
#>  7     6 GSC            Hybr… aka …    4.4        7409 THC 1… CBG 1%            
#>  8     7 Zkittlez       Indi… aka …    4.5         857 THC 2… CBG 1%            
#>  9     8 OG Kush        Hybr… aka …    4.3        5476 THC 1… CBD 0%            
#> 10     9 Mac 1          Hybr… aka …    4.7         353 THC 2… CBG 1%            
#> # ℹ 5,110 more rows
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: Main_Effect <chr>, Terpene <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There's also [kaggler](https://github.dev/mkearney/kaggler) package and option to use official Python API package though reticulate